# My first React project: UI for minesweeper

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am currently learning React and tried building the UI of a basic minesweeper game as a first project. My goal was to write simple, re-usable components. I will go over each of them and do my best to explain the rationale behind them and, after that, explain how they are all tied together in the main `App` component. Please let me know if anything I have written can be done in a more efficient or idiomatic way.

As said before I have built the **UI** using React, the game logic is separate from the the React code. The whole project can be seen on [github](https://github.com/LouisonCalbrix/minesweeper) and the game can be actually played on my [neocities website](https://louisono.neocities.org). One last precision: for readability reasons, the following is **jsx code**.

### The Picker component

The picker component is used to create a group of labeled radio-buttons. It comes with a function `checkedRadio(groupName)` which returns the html `value` attribute of the chosen option. Note that I render a collection of elements without using `key`, here's why:

- each radio-button has an `id` attribute to make it work with the html `label`, I feel like adding a unique `key` would be redundant
- the list of radio-button shouldn't change over time, which means no re-render, and thus no need for a `key`

```
/* Picker component:
 * Return a group of radio buttons.
 * Expected props:
 *      - name: the html name for the group of radio buttons
 *      - descriptions: a sequence of strings that each describes an option in the
 *          group
 *      - defaultPick: the index of the description for the default option picked
 *      - onChange: a function called when the radio button checked changes, this
 *          function can take as an argument an object of the form
 *          { description, indexOfDescription }
 *      - radioClass: the class name for every option of the Picker
 * Additional props will be attached to the wrapping div.
 */
const Picker = function({name, descriptions, defaultPick, onChange, radioClass, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <div {...rest}>
            {descriptions.map((description, i) => {
                return (
                    <span className={radioClass}>
                    <input type='radio'
                               name={name}
                               value={description}
                               id={`${ name }-${ description }`}
                               defaultChecked={i===defaultPick}
                               onChange={() => onChange({description, i})} />
                    <label htmlFor={`${ name }-${ description }`}>{description}</label>
                    </span>);
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

/* Return the value of the radio button checked in the group of radio buttons
 * that is named groupName.
 * Will throw an error if no such group is found.
 */
const checkedRadio = function(groupName) {
    const grp = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=${groupName}`);
    for (const node of grp)
        if (node.checked)
            return node.value;
    throw new Error(`no radio group of name ${ groupName }`);
}
```

### The Matrix component

This component is used to render a rectangular 2D array of data. It uses a `Row` component to render lines of cells. How each cell is render is up to the user, and a `cellComponent` should be provided for both of these components to work as intended. Here as well, I am not using any `key`, it is up to the user to give a `key` (or not) to their cells. Given that the user can make their cells have `key`s,  I figured that `Row` elements don't need any `key` of their own.

```
/* Matrix component:
 * Return a table-like element.
 * Expected props:
 *      - array: the 2D array that must be translated into a pseudo-table
 *      - rowClass: the class name for every row in the Matrix
 *      - onClick, onContextMenu: functions to be called when a cell of the
 *          Matrix is respectively left-clicked or right-clicked
 *      - cellComponent: a component to be instanciated for every cell of the
 *          given 2D array. Such a component should accept props of the form
 *          { cell, x, y, onClick, onContextMenu }
 * Additional props will be attached to the wrapping div.
 */
const Matrix = function({array, rowClass, onClick, onContextMenu, cellComponent, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <div {...rest}>
            {array.map((row, y) => {
                return (
                    <Row
                      className={rowClass}
                      row={row}
                      y={y}
                      onClick={onClick}
                      onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
                      cellComponent={cellComponent} />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

/* Row component:
 * Return a flat sequence of cells. This component is meant to be instanciated
 * by the Matrix component.
 * Expected props:
 *      - row: the flat (1D) array that must be translated into a Row
 *      - y: the number of the Row in the Matrix
 *      - onClick, onContextMenu: functions to be called when a cell of the
 *          Row is respectively left-clicked or right-clicked
 *      - cellComponent: a component to be instanciated for every cell of the
 *          given 2D array. Such a component should accept props of the form
 *          { cell, x, y, onClick, onContextMenu }
 * Additional props will be attached to the wrapping div.
 */
const Row = function({row, y, onClick, onContextMenu, cellComponent, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <div {...rest}>
            {row.map((cell, x) => cellComponent({x, y, onClick, onContextMenu, cell}))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

### My own `cellComponent`: the mineCell component

This is the `cellComponent` that is meant to be called by the `Matrix` component. It is meant to represent cells in a minesweeper game, and therefore relies more on the logic part (which isn't covered here). `mines.UNREV`, `mines.BOMB` and `mines.FLAG` are constants defined in the logic part that are used to differentiate between kinds of cell, here they are used to apply different styles to different cells. Still in the logic part, each cell can be represented be a single character, which is the actual `cell` argument passed to the `mineCell` component.

```
// Map to determine the CSS class of a cell based on its value
const cellClasses = new Map(
    [[mines.UNREV, 'tile-unrevealed'],
    [mines.BOMB, 'tile-bomb'],
    [mines.FLAG, 'tile-flag']]
);

// Cell component for the Minesweeper game
const mineCell = function({x, y, onClick, onContextMenu, cell}) {
    let className = cellClasses.get(cell);
    return (
        <span
          className={className}
          onClick={() => onClick(x, y)}
          onContextMenu={(evt) => { evt.preventDefault(); onContextMenu(x, y) }}>
            {cell}
        </span>
    );
}
```

### Where everything is tied together: the App component

Let's have a look at the `render` function. It uses a `Picker` element (with difficulties defined in the logic part as `descriptions`) to let the user choose the difficulty setting and a `Matrix` element to render all the cells of the game.

```
// labels for the difficulty settings
const descriptions = Array.from(mines.difficulties.keys());

// Map to determine the reset button css class depending on the minefield state
const resetClasses = new Map(
    [[mines.WON, 'reset-won'],
    [mines.LOST, 'reset-lost'],
    [mines.PLAYING, 'reset-normal']]
);

App.prototype.render = function() {
    const minefield = this.state.minefield;
    let resetButtonClass = resetClasses.get(minefield.state);
    return (
        <div id='app'>
            <Picker
              id='picker'
              descriptions={descriptions}
              name='difficulty'
              defaultPick={1}
              onChange={() => this.changeDifficulty()}
              radioClass='radio-button'/>
            <button
              id='reset-button'
              className={resetButtonClass}
              onClick={() => this.resetGame()}
              alt='button to reset the game'>
            </button>
            <Matrix
              id='game'
              array={minefield.view}
              rowClass='mines-row'
              onClick={(x, y) => this.mineviewLeftClick(x, y)}
              onContextMenu={(x, y) => this.mineviewRightClick(x, y)}
              cellComponent={mineCell}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here's how the `App` component is defined. The chosen difficulty can be retrieved at any moment by finding which option is checked in the difficulty `Picker`. The `state` only contains the `Minefield` instance. (Quick precision about the `Minefield` constructor defined in the logic part: it requires a position to instantiate any object so that the first cell clicked is not a bomb. For that reason anything displayed before the first click of a game is actually a dummy minefield.)

```
// Dummy minefield used when the game hasn't started yet
const DUMMY = 'du';
const dummyMinefield = function([width, height, _]) {
    return {
        view: Array(height).fill(Array(width).fill(mines.UNREV)),
        state: DUMMY
    };
}

const App = function(props) {
    React.Component.call(this, props);
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'difficulty', {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() { return checkedRadio('difficulty'); }
    });
    this.state = {
        minefield: dummyMinefield(mines.difficulties.get(descriptions[1])),
    };
}
App.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);
App.prototype.constructor = App;
```

The rest is the different functions: changing difficulty, starting the game over, clicking on a cell, putting a flag on a cell.

```
// Change the difficulty picked
App.prototype.changeDifficulty = function() {
    this.setState({
        minefield: dummyMinefield(mines.difficulties.get(this.difficulty)),
    });
}

// Reset the on-going game of minesweeper
App.prototype.resetGame = function() {
    this.setState({
        minefield: dummyMinefield(mines.difficulties.get(this.difficulty)),
    });
}

// Handle click events on the Matrix component that represents the minefield

/* Handle left click events
 * Reveal the minefield's cell at coordinates x, y if the minefield is not a dummy.
 * Create a minefield otherwise
 */
App.prototype.mineviewLeftClick = function(x, y) {
    if (this.state.minefield.state===DUMMY) {
        const [width, height, bombs] = mines.difficulties.get(this.difficulty);
        const minefield = new mines.Minefield(width, height, [x, y], bombs);
        this.setState({minefield});
    }
    else {
        const minefield = this.state.minefield.reveal([x, y]);
        this.setState({minefield});
    }
}

/* Handle right click events
 * Flag the minefield's cell at coordinates x, y if the minefield is not a dummy.
 */
App.prototype.mineviewRightClick = function(x, y) {
    if (this.state.minefield.state!==DUMMY) {
        const minefield = this.state.minefield.flag([x, y]);
        this.setState({minefield});
    }
}
```

That's it, I hope it's not to long or too vague and I am looking forward to hear advice on how to write more idiomatic React code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use `class`es** instead of creating a `function` that manually inheirts from `React.Component`. This will also allow you to more concisely define properties and methods. For example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        minefield: dummyMinefield(mines.difficulties.get(descriptions[1])),
    };
    get difficulty() {
        return checkedRadio('difficulty');
    }
    changeDifficulty() {
        this.setState({
            minefield: dummyMinefield(mines.difficulties.get(this.difficulty)),
        });
    }
    // ...
```

Classes are a lot nicer for organizing code than `function`s and assigning to the `.prototype`.

Or, even better:

**Consider functional components** - React [recommends trying functional components and hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components) instead of class components in new code. To me, the operation and lifecycle of functional components is more intuitive than for class components. If you try them, you may find that they make maintenance easier.

**Avoid native DOM methods** when possible - with React, whenever you see the use of a native DOM method like `querySelector` (or `.children` or `.style`, etc.), take a step back and consider if there's another way. *Usually*, the use of such methods can be avoided by using React's state and render methods instead.

The only part with this issue is with the difficulty picker. Ideally, the `checkedRadio` function would be removed completely. (If you decide to keep it anyway, at least change the name to something like `getCheckedRadioName` - the variable doesn't *hold* the checked radio button, it *returns* the checked radio name)

Put the difficulty into the app's state instead, and make the Picker a controlled component instead (so that selection changes go into state). Pass down the difficulty value and setter into the picker. Something like this:

```
const App = () => {
    // these get passed as selectedDescription and setSelectedDescription
    const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState('EASY');
```

```
const Picker = function({name, descriptions, selectedDescription, setSelectedDescription, radioClass, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <div {...rest}>
            {descriptions.map((description) => {
                return (
                    <span className={radioClass}>
                    <input type='radio'
                               name={name}
                               value={description}
                               id={`${ name }-${ description }`}
                               checked={description === selectedDescription}
                               onChange={() => setSelectedDescription(description)} />
                    <label htmlFor={`${ name }-${ description }`}>{description}</label>
                    </span>);
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Rest parameters** There are a whole lot of props in the component. Rather than allowing for as many additional props as the caller wants, you might consider using a *single* prop instead of the `rest`, and give it an informative name. Maybe:

```
, radioClass, pickerContainerProps = {}}) {
  return (
    <div {...pickerContainerProps}>
```

**Name** I don't *think* the `name` prop needs to be passed down - it's an implementation detail that only the Picker cares about, after all, and only for the purposes of grouping the radios. Maybe have Picker come up with a name instead?

```
const inputNameRef = useRef();
if (!inputNameRef.current) {
  inputNameRef.current = makeRandomString();
}
// proceed to use `inputNameRef.current` instead of `name`
```

You can also avoid the `id`s and the `htmlFor` by making the `<input>` a child of the `<label>`.

**JSDoc** The standard way to document functions in JS is with [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) or a similar format. In contrast, using something like

```
/* Picker component:
 * Return a group of radio buttons.
 * Expected props:
 *      - name: the html name for the group of radio buttons
```

while certainly *useful*, isn't quite in the expected format for good IDEs to take advantage of it. [Article with examples](https://www.javascriptjanuary.com/blog/autocomplete-in-react-using-jsdoc).

Here's a small example of how VSCode could inform the developer of the expected props by putting your comments into JSDoc format:

[image]

**Consider using plain arrow functions everywhere** instead of `function`s - arrow functions alone are a much more common convention in React. They're a bit more concise, both in the lack of `function` and their ability to implicitly return.

**Spread props** and use shorthand properties, if you like - when you only have to list each prop *once* when rendering rather than twice, that's one less potential for a typo-based problem to manifest. For example, this:

```
<Row
  className={rowClass}
  row={row}
  y={y}
  onClick={onClick}
  onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
  cellComponent={cellComponent}
/>
```

could be:

```
<Row
  className={rowClass}
  {...{
    row,
    y,
    onClick,
    onContextMenu,
    cellComponent
  }}
/>
```

(you could also use object rest to collect all of these but `className` into a single object in the parameter list of `Matrix`)

**Use `const` instead of `let`** - see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6). Especially in React, where functional programming is preferred (and sometimes necessary), it's good to indicate to the reader of the code that even the *possibility* of reassignment is impossible. Both `let` uses I see can be replaced with `const`.

**Destructure**, if you like. Hopefully you'll be using functional components instead of class components, but if not, you can change stuff like this:

```
const minefield = this.state.minefield;
```

to

```
const { minefield } = this.state;
```

**Cell text** When there's a visible mine on a cell, the cell text becomes "X". When there's a visible flag on a cell, the cell text becomes "P". These texts, while invisible normally, become visible if the board is highlighted. Same for unvisited cells, which have `.`s. Consider not rendering those texts at all - only render text if the text is a number.

**Face tooltip** You have

```
alt='button to reset the game'
```

Some people may not be familiar with Minesweeper's UI. Consider adding a tooltip as well, so that someone hovering over the face can see that it's clickable. Maybe add a `:hover` effect as well.

If you wanted to make things fancy, you could also change the face to the hesitant "O" face when the mouse is pressed down on a cell but not released yet.

**Make dragging harder to do accidentally** It's very, very easy to accidentally drag the main interface by clicking down *anywhere* inside the interface and then dragging. This makes it impossible to reconsider one's choice if one clicks down on a cell but hasn't released the mouse yet. Consider allowing the drag action only with the `.close-bar` at the top.

Comment: Thank you for your insights! I disagree with you on a few points (namely the use of classes and DOM methods), however, I strongly appreciate your answer overall and your advice will surely help me enhance the quality of my code for future projects.